# Series proof validity and questions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I want to prove that: For all $t \in \mathbb{N}$, show that
$$
\sum_{k=2^{t-1}+1}^{2^{t}} \frac{1}{k} \geq \frac{1}{2}
$$

My attempt:
$$
\sum_{k=2^{t-1}+1}^{2^{t}} \frac{1}{k}=\frac{1}{2^{t-1}+1}+\frac{1}{2^{t-1}+2}+\frac{1}{2^{t-1}+3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{t}}
$$
for any $k \in\left\{1,2,3, \ldots, 2^{t-1}\right]$ we have
$$
2^{t-1}+k \leq 2^{t} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2^{t-1}+k} \geq \frac{1}{2^{t}}
$$
Using the above inequality we get
$$
\sum_{k=2^{t-1}+1}^{2^{t}}=\frac{1}{2^{t-1}+1}+\frac{1}{2^{t-1}+2}+\frac{1}{2^{t-1}+3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{t}} \geq \frac{1}{2^{t}}+\frac{1}{2^{t}}+\frac{1}{2^{t}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{t}}=\frac{2^{t-1}}{2^{t}}=\frac{1}{2}
$$
I want to show this inequality is true so that I can show that the limit of the sequence of partial sums $ \sum_{k=1}^{2^t} {\frac{1}{k}}$ diverges to infinity, If I can conclude this, can I also argue that since this is a subsequence of $ \sum_{k=1}^{n} {\frac{1}{k}}$ so that $ \sum_{k=1}^{n} {\frac{1}{k}}$ must diverges as $n$ goes to infinity or the subsequence is not a valid argument here?

Comment: This proof is fine.

Comment: This is, indeed, precisely the standard argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is valid. Regarding your questions, you should consider, as a consequence of your result, that:
$$\sum_{t=1}^n \sum_{k={2^{t-1}+1}}^{2^t} {\frac 1k}\geq \frac n2$$ Then, if you let ${n\to \infty}$, your proof will be completed.